# Await and parallelism

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following call:

```
Getstuff(await getFoo, await getBar,  await getQuux);
```

Inside `Getstuff`:

```
var fooLookup = getFoo?.Entries.ToLookup(x => x.Something);
var barDictionary = getBar?.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something);
var quuxDictionary = getQuux.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something);
```

I have the impression this misses a concurrency opportunity that could be given by:

```
Getstuff(getFoo, getBar, getQuux);
```

and `Getstuff`:

```
Task<getFooLookup> fooLookup1;
Task<getBarDictionary> barDictionary1;
Task<getQuuxDictionary> quuxDictionary1;

Task.WaitAll(fooLookup1 = getFoo, barDictionary1 = getBar, quuxDictionary1 = getQuux);

var fooLookup = fooLookup1.Result.Entries.ToLookup(x => x.Something); 
var barDictionary = barLookup1.Result?.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something); 
var quuxDictionary = quuxLookup1.Result?.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something);
```

Would the second option be parallelized (if it works), and if so, what risks would I be incurring for example a database lookup were involved? Any simplification I might be missing?

EDIT

The three parameters are assigned like so:

```
async Task<foo> GetFoo(ICollection<Guid> stuffList) { .. some async code.. }
...
var getFoo = GetFoo(list);
```

Comment: your code example is way too incomplete to comment on its behavior.

Comment: If `getFoo`/`getBar`/`getQuux` are tasks, then the code is already running concurrently.

Comment: @StephenCleary even in the first case where we have three awaits?

Comment: @OtávioDécio Again, *it depends on the specifics of the code* which you haven't shown.  It could be, or it could not be, depending on the specifics of the code.  You could write a program with either behavior.

Comment: @Servy not sure what could be more specific. If I am awaiting on something it is "awaitable" and should return a Task of some sort

Comment: @Evk that's exactly my doubt.

Comment: Well it's easy to verify and as my test shows it's indeed the case (not that I had any doubt before Stephen's comment)

Comment: @OtávioDécio Indeed, we know that the expression is awaitable, and thus resolves to a `Task`, but we don't know *when* the task it resolves to is created, or when it actually starts performing whatever operation the `Task` represents.  That will depend on the specifics of the code.

Comment: @Evk The code doesn't show enough to comment on when the task is started.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean now. If tasks were started before (like `getFoo = SomeAsyncMethod()`) - then they are already running at the point you call `await getFoo`, all 3 of them.

Comment: @pep You have no idea if the second task starts before or after the first task finishes; the code doesn't provide enough information to state either way.

Comment: @Servy would the Getstuff method be entered after the three of them finished concurrently? If so the whole question is a moot point.

Comment: @OtávioDécio We couldn't possibly say, because you haven't provided enough information to know how the code behaves.  It might, or it might not, depending on what the code you haven't shown looks like.

Comment: @OtávioDécio Servy is right to request more info. Whether they will run concurrently or not depends on if `getFoo` tasks were already started at the moment you await them or not (and if yes - they are already running, so already concurrently). So you have to show how exactly you create `getFoo` tasks.

Comment: @Evk We know they're started at the moment they're `awaited` (if they aren't the code will deadlock) what we don't know is if they're started before the expressions are evaluated.

Comment: @Servy I added some extra info. I am looking for a simple scenario where the variables are assign with the call of an async method.

Comment: @OtávioDécio You still haven't provided enough information.  By providing different implementations of the code not shown you could still get either behavior.  Provide a *complete* program if you want to have a meaningful explanation of how that program behaves.

Comment: @Servy maybe you can answer describing different possibilities? Question seems to be not about concrete situation but approach in general. I'm particulary interested what implementation of `GetFoo` do I need to provide to make that code run sequentially.

Comment: @Evk Describing every single possible implementation of a program and the specific semantics of all of them is *way* too broad.  There are *lots* of different ways of writing programs, and they're going to have wildly varying semantics.

Comment: @pep Even assuming they're methods, and not something else, still doesn't tell you of the opeartions will happen concurrently or sequentially.  You could implement the methods such that either would happen.  You are right however that the implementation of methods like that can not only determine whether they happen in parallel or in sequence, but whether the operations themselves happen asynchronously or concurrently; yet another dimension of semantics that can vary based on the code not shown.

Comment: @OtávioDécio I think you might be interested to read this:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve parallelism and you have 3 methods that return say `Task<T1>`, `Task<T2>`, `Task<T3>`, it's pretty simple: start all the tasks first, but don't await any, and only then await, either all of them together with `await Task.WhenAll()` (ideally; otherwise less preferably with the blocking `Task.WaitAll()`), or individually with `await` for each.  So something like this:

```
Task<T1> getFooTask = GetFoo();
Task<T2> getBarTask = GetBar();
Task<T3> getQuuxTask = GetQuux();
// All tasks started (or at least queued) now, potentially (probably) running in parallel

await Task.WhenAll(getFooTask, getBarTask, getQuuxTask);
// All tasks complete now
```

You can then inspect the results individually:

```
T1 fooResults = await getFooTask;
T2 barResults = await getBarTask;
T3 quuxResults = await getQuuxTask;
```

or perhaps:

```
Getstuff(await getFooTask, await getBarTask,  await getQuuxTask);
```

You can also use `.Result` without blocking at this point, but using `await` again refactors better.

To await them individually (and still achieve parallelism), just drop the `await Task.WhenAll()` line.

As a side note, dropping the `await Task.WhenAll()` is a simple example showing the benefit of using `await` on a completed task instead of `.Result`.  If you had used `.Result` instead, the behaviour would have changed from non-blocking to blocking.

Comment: So, what's the benefit of using `Task.WhenAll` in the above example? Since I can do just fine without - why add it at all?

Comment: In this particular example, probably not a lot. Maybe save a couple of context switches, but that's relatively insignificant. It depends on context, though; if the requirement is to not process any individual result until all tasks are completed, it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is pretty vague. I am assuming here that all three of these awaitable tasks are already running concurrently, such that your original code is synchronously awaiting the individual results.

First, it's important to point out that your proposed change to the code does materially and detrimentally change the basic behavior of the code. Where the code used to potentially allow for asynchronous waiting of completion, your proposed change forces the thread to synchronously wait for completion. This should be avoided.

I'd thought that was reasonably obvious, but judging from the comments, there are folks who are confused about my intent here, hence this explicit caveat. With that in mind…

Your second example, ignoring your syntax errors, can (and should) be simplified to:

```
Task.WaitAll(getFoo, getBar, getQuux);

var fooLookup = getFoo.Result.Entries.ToLookup(x => x.Something); 
var barDictionary = getBar.Result?.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something); 
var quuxDictionary = getQuux.Result?.Entries.ToDictionary(x => x.Something);
```

But in reality, if your method is not itself inherently an asynchronous operation, you should not force that onto it. It is simple enough for the caller to do that as needed:

```
Task.WaitAll(getFoo, getBar, getQuux);
GetStuff(await getFoo, await getBar, await getQuux);
```

The `WaitAll()` enforces the synchronous behavior your example has. Again, it's not that this is desirable. It's just that this is required, in order to be consistent with your example.

In this way, all three tasks are assured of having completed before you try to pass their results to `GetStuff()` and `GetStuff()` can remain its nice, simple synchronous self.

Using `await` just helps unpack exceptions, making them easier to handle, log, etc. You could of course use e.g. `getFoo.Result` instead of `await getFoo`.

But you don't even need that! Assuming these three tasks are all already running, then awaiting all three in sequence doesn't in any way prevent them from running concurrently. Even if the first is the last to finish, by the time that one finishes, the other two will have also and those awaits will complete immediately.

And importantly, doing it in this way prevents the thread from being blocked while you wait for the results to be available. This is much better than the synchronous waiting you'd proposed as an alternative.

In other words, your original code is fine, and better than what you'd proposed as an alternative. Don't change it.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. I also don't quite understand the serial downvoters plaguing this site.

Comment: @OtávioDécio You appreciate being given an incorrect answer to your question?  That seems...odd.  It also seems rather mean to upvote an incorrect answer to a question, as it'll just confuse future readers into thinking that it contains correct information.

Comment: @Servy: how about you explain in what way the above answer is **incorrect**. Or even **not useful**.

Comment: @Servy I appreciate Peter's civility regardless, which is sorely lacking in this site.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well for starters, you're specifically stating in multiple places that you're making assumptions, and you don't have a basis for those assumptions, so your conclusions based on those unwarranted assumptions are therefore meaningless.  Your proposed changes will also have wildly varying effects based on the specific of the code not shown.  It won't ever have the effects you explain, under any of those situations, but the actual effects it *will* have have a number of possibilities.  Your assessment of `await` is also completely incorrect, just in entirety.

Comment: @OtávioDécio You think that [sarcasic remarks against neutral feedback on a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866355/await-and-parallelism/42867017?noredirect=1#comment72840422_42867017) is civil?  Or [asserting that people providing valuable feedback on the quality of posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866355/await-and-parallelism/42867017?noredirect=1#comment72840850_42867017) are a plauge is civil?   Someone telling you information you don't like isn't being uncivil.

Comment: Note that `Task.WaitAll` is not the best thing to use here. Say you have async method in which you do that 'Task.WaitAll' and suppose you call it from UI thread in some UI application (and you don't await anything before you call it). First part of async method (before the first await) will execute on current (UI) thread, including your `Task.WaitAll`, so UI thread will be (unnecessary) blocked until all 3 tasks will be completed.

Comment: @Servy: **1)** a down-vote is negative feedback, not neutral feedback. **2)** my comment wasn't sarcastic; I genuinely am amused when people down-vote but can't be bothered to explain themselves. **3)** _"Your assessment of await is also completely incorrect"_ -- "completely" is remarkably strong, for a situation where I am confident it doesn't apply.

Comment: @Servy: **4)** _"you're making assumptions"_ -- yes, that's perfectly reasonable when information is incomplete but a useful answer can still be provided. **5)** _"you don't have a basis for those assumptions"_ -- that's your own **subjective** assessment. I obviously disagree.

Comment: @Evk: _"Task.WaitAll is not the best thing to use here"_ -- I agree. But it's in the answer simply for a point of reference, based on the OP's question, as a way of comparison to the also-synchronous use of `Result` in the called method. I don't think every Q&A regarding async/await has to cover the same old ground of reminding every person that synchronously waiting for asynchronous completions is almost always the wrong thing to do, especially when those synchronous waits aren't part of the practice recommended in the answer itself.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 1) It's feedback that the post is of negative value.  It's a neutral way of providing that feedback. 2) For something that you *genuinely* love you seem to have gotten rather upset at not getting comments. 3) Then I suggest looking at an intro tutorial into `await`, so that you can improve  your understanding of its semantics, which are *radically* different from calling `Result` in way too many ways to explain to you in a comment.

Comment: @Servy: _"you seem to have gotten rather upset"_ -- I'm not upset about anything here at all. You are reading **way** too much into, well...something. I have no idea what, or where you got that idea. And I understand the semantics of `await` just fine, thank you very much.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 4) When a question doesn't provide sufficient information to be answerable the appropriate reaction is to work to *fix the question* such that it actually contains enough information to be answered, at which point a correct answer can actually be provided.  Simply guessing at what you think is going on causes *lots* of problems, particularly when your guesses are wrong, making the answer *not useful*.

Comment: @Servy: _"particularly when your guesses are wrong"_ -- all due respect, it is not for you to judge whether my assumptions/guesses are wrong or not. Only the OP can provide that information. Your assertion that my answer is wrong is based only on **your own assumptions** about the OP's scenario.

Comment: @PeterDuniho but you are using Task.WaitAll in two places, and in second place there is no synchronous waiting for Result.

Comment: @Evk: both of those are places are simply re-stated versions of the synchronous code the OP postulated. _Not_ using `WaitAll()` would change the behavior of that code, rendering those examples _different_ from that originally presented by the OP. The whole point of those examples was to provide code that works like the OP's code, but is written "better" (where "better" simply means, "not as bad", and not necessary "the right way"). If you'll note, my actual recommendation is to not do any of that synchronous waiting at all, and to just leave the original `await`-ing code as-is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not saying that the assumption is wrong, I'm saying that we have no idea whether or not it's right or wrong.  You're providing an answer to a question without even knowing what the question is asking.  Answers are expected to be demonstrably correct and you can't demonstrate that the answer is correct because the question doesn't contain enough information to do so.  The fact that (that part) of the answer can't be proven wrong because the question is unanswerable doesn't mean it's automatically correct.

Comment: _"Answers are expected to be demonstrably correct"_ -- one way to demonstrate that an answer is correct, is for the OP to accept it. You've down-voted an answer that is not demonstrably incorrect, based on your own assumptions. That's your prerogative, of course. I just find it funny. Sorry if my taking amusement at your actions bothers you. It's not my intent to hurt your feelings.